# Link prediction to predict edges without common neighbours

Tags: python, graph, networkx, logistic-regression, prediction

The main methods used for link prediction in a graph documented in the package networkx "Link prediction algorithm" includes:

1. jaccard_coefficient
2. adamic_adar_index

Can be found here https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.link_prediction.html.

The problem occurred when I have two nodes without any common neighbors, all these algorithms output 0, thus might create data leakage when validating my machine learning model with testing data.

For example, I made the graph into positive and negative samples (binary prediction problem). The positive link (denoted by 1) came from the edges of the existing graph, where the negative links are randomly generated (denoted by 0). The negative link always outputs 0 in these algorithms (jaccard_coefficient and adamic_adar_index) and the positive is always > 0. The problem is akin to logistics regression.

I have also tried node2vec, but didn't work well.

The testing data we were given includes 4000 links, with 2000 being true. And I found most of them (greater than 3000) does not have common neighbours.

The graph is a undirected graph.

Comment: How large is your graph? What are the current AUROCs you retrieve for the tested methods? (and you should always work with the latest networkx and docs: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/link_prediction.html) There are quite many link prediction heuristics and methods around, for example search for link prediction review on google scholar

Comment: My current AUC is 0.926. My aim is getting above 0.98 or at lease 0.95. The graph have 4000 vertex and 20000 edges. Yeah I had a look at the networkx docs. But does not solve my problem when predicting edges without common neighbours.

Comment: I'm predicting "probability" for each possible edges. I have tried neural network using categlory_crossentropy and SoftMax. In additional,  I have also tried other simple methods such as logistic regression and random forest.

Comment: You may also want to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669360/the-best-measure-to-improve-link-prediction

Comment: @Sparky05 I have. That question seems to suggest "adamic_adar_index". But this does not work well when there are ZERO common neighbours.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the two papers linked in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider the shared k-step neighbors as in the Katz index described in this paper: [1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037843711000991X?casa_token=4GfcchkMbQUAAAAA:IUbfYjn46S4JmkASSzVxPE83K-Alik0KVFtI4Gy5ZXjQUhhmnwuuye-HnvSQjpMCYmGMoI6Q)

The idea is, roughly speaking, to consider the number of common neighbors, common 2-step neighbors, 3-step neighbors, etc. with some weight decreasing with the step. So direct shared neighbors should count more than shared 3-step neighbors. To save on computation, you could consider only up to 2-step neighbors. Another way to think about this is from a random walk perspective, also discussed in the paper.

Comment: Are there any implementation of this algorithm using networkx?

Comment: "some weight decreasing" what would be a reasonable weight?

Comment: I don't think something like this is directly implemented. You could write a function that counts the number of neighbors, and second order neighbors (though take care not to double count). As for the weight - simply multiply the contribution of common k'th order neighbors by  X^k for some X in (0,1). I would try .5 or .1 and see what comes out.